# angular applies style incorrectly

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two DOMs as shown in the figures. The problem is the circled <div class=panel-heading largeText"> in the first template gets a style of [_ngcontent-c1] while the same <div> gets the style of panel-primary > .panel-heading. The templates are shown in Figure 3 and 4.   Does anyone know what the problem is? Where can I find the documentation of [class.active] attribute?  Thanks.

Figure 1:
[image: HepC]

Figure 2:
[image: Vista]

Figure 3:

```html
<div *ngIf="show">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading largeText">
        Hep C Note
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-md 12">
            <!--<form #hepcFormVar="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(hepcFormVar)" novalidate>-->
            <form #hepcFormVar="ngForm" novalidate>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Patient:</label>
                <span name="patientName" class="largeText">{{patientName}}</span>
              </div>
```

Figure 4:

```html
<div *ngIf="show">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading largeText">
        Vista Note
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-md 12">
            <!--<form #vistaNoteFormVar="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(vistaNoteFormVar)" novalidate>-->
            <form #vistaNoteFormVar="ngForm" novalidate>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="patientName">Patient:</label>
                <span name="patientName" id="patientName" class="largeText">{{patientName}}</span>
              </div>
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] that actually leads to this.

Comment: ... As actual code please, not pictures of code.

Comment: I couldn't get what are you asking.
*except the strings in the text nodes in the are slightly different*
?

Comment: One is a child of `vista-note` the other of `hepc-note` - I'm guessing these are different components, each with their own styles, and `largeText` is defined differently in each?

Comment: That's not "angular" applying the style but how the browser is interpreting the style. What does your less/css look like? From the pics it looks like there is something specifically setup for the rule in each case and all we are seeing is the browser interpretation at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah!  I used separate css for each of the templates.  I thought largeText was a Bootstrap css class.  The problem is resolved when I added the style in the css used by the Vist-Note component.